# Batch Decollating Directory of PDFs and Bar Code Imposing

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I have a directory of PDFs.  They are all different, but they all have 5 pages.  I need to insert a bar code on each page for each PDF. After this process I need to combine and decollate every PDF.  Essentially there would be 5 different PDFs created.  The first would contain all page ones from every PDF, the second the second page, etc.

I need to find a tool, or a toolset, that would allow me to accomplish this.  I'm willing to program my own solution but I'm not even sure what would be the most efficient language to attack it with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was using Perl with the PDF::Reuse and PDF::Reuse::BarCode libraries to get all PDFS in the directory, pull the pages I wanted, put the barcode and save out to a new PDF.